# Create a sample audio app player for Alexa Amazon

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am a very very newbie on programming a skill on Alexa but I would like to create a very simple sample to play on my Amazon Echo a MP3 file hosted on a https server.

I create a skill and succeed in matching the skill to my Lambda Aws code.

But anyone has a simple code Lambda AWS to play a MP3 (not using SSML) as my file duration is 15 minutes.

Example :
"Alexa, open my fave music"
And Alexa will play my file hosted on my https Server.

The objective is to see how to play a MP3 file using the AWS Lambda code

I found sample code  but didn't succeed to launch any code

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've looked into Alexa github samples. But there's a sample code that you can just edit the mp3 url.

https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player/tree/mainline/single-stream

Also don't forget to turn on the "Audio Player" interface in Alexa developer console for your skill.

[Audio Player Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUXgv.png)